# Is it possible to activate bluetooth only on a wireless card?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, bluetooth, intel, realtek

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

My computer came with built-in Realtek rtl8821ae wifi with bluetooth. I've since added an Intel 7260 wifi card to my computer and deactivated the Realtek device.

I was wondering if it's possible to do wifi through the Intel card and bluetooth-only through the Realtek device simultaneously. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not? It should be possible. But what is the reason?

Comment: @Pilot6 The Intel card must be a better wifi card but lack bluetooth support.

Comment: The intel card apparently alsohas Bluetooth support, but is not supported on Linux from what I've found. If that's not the case, I'd love to just use the Bluetooth functionality through the Intel card.